# How to throw sprites at random direction in unity

Tags: unity, c#, unityscript

[image: Here What I want to achieve]

I have 2 Questions;

1.How do i throw square in different directions on every click while maintaining cyan border restriction

2.How to keep rotating square after i click in z-axis

[Check This Video For Hint](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S4-AVu_8SSU)

Comment: welcome to Game Development! Could you specific what you gave tried to accomplish this? It helps people answer your question!

Comment: Do you want it to be random or just within the scope of a breakout game?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pick a random direction in a cone defined by two angles, then you simply create a random angle between those values (`minAngle + random * (maxAngle - minAngle)`), then you use trigonometric equations to convert it into a vector:

```
x = cos(angle)
y = sin(angle)
```